# Update 3D Scene Programmatically to be Showed in Blend4Web WebPlayer (JSON)

Tags: json, 3d, blender

I created a blender project, exported it as JSON+BIN files and showed it through the blend4web webplayer. Everything goes fine until my need to change the JSON file programmatically to add/remove a new 3D object (e.g. a cube or rectangle). I want to renderize the already showed 3D model adding or removing a 3D object. However, since the exportation of a project to blend4web generate a .bin file, if I change only the .json the model was not showed as expected. Considering this scenario, the unique way to change the model is modifing the .blend file and exports it again from Blender. But based on my need, I can't add a new 3D object in a Blender project programmatically considering the .json file. Additionally, the .json file which I am updating/using is considering data retrieved from a Database, such data indicates how and the position where the new 3D object will be displayed in the scene, which hinder me to use Blender to create a 3D Model modificated.

In this perspective, I need help to identify:

- Which is the best way to change the scene and show it in blend4web programmatically and mainly considering a .json as an input for the model?
- Is there any python script to user a blend4web .json file as an input to be compiled,  without the Blender project and regenerate the .bin file, making it possible to show correctly my 3D model using the blend4web webplayer for JSON files?
- Or, is there some (easy) way to modify a project from Blender considering data in JSON format, compile and generate the files to be shown programmatically by the blend4web webplayer (for JSON)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you know that blender provides python module? By using that module you can do everithing that Blender does.
I mean, you can change objects (everithing) in scene like in Blender from the python.

Comment: Yes, I know! Thanks for you tip! But I really want to find an sollution considering the JSON files, ready to be used by the blend4web webplayer. The first attempt that I am trying to find is the compilation of a JSON file to generate the .bin file to allow it to be showed using the blend4web.

Or, Do you want to say that is possible to change the blender project in a similar way to just add or remove some lines in a JSON file?

Comment: Additionally, I am starting with Blender... So, sorry for my ignorance!